# Ember.js hasMany/belongsTo custom foreign key

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I would like to add an `employee` *belongsTo* a `business` and a `business` *hasMany* `employees` relationship but the `foreign key` is `businessId` instead of `business_id`. Where can I configure Ember to allow `businessId` to be the foreign key?

In fact how can I make `modelId` the format for all foreign keys?

we are using `Ember data 1.13`, `ember-cli 1.13`

controllers/employee.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  business: DS.belongsTo('business', { async: true })
});
```

controllers/business.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  employees: DS.hasMany('employee', { async: true })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a [custom serializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html) to transform the desired key in your JSON payload to match the property defined in your model:

```
  //in app/serializers/employees
  import Ember from 'ember';
  import DS from 'ember-data';

  export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizeHash: {
      employees: function(hash) {
        hash.business_id = hash.businessId;
        delete hash.businessId;
      return hash;
    }
  }
  });
```